# Nuxt3 - TS2339:Property 'replaceAll' does not exist on type 'string | string[]' in Nuxt3

Tags: html, typescript, vue.js, nuxtjs3

Hello I've been trying to use the `replaceAll()` method in nuxt3 project and It gave some weird error.

[image: Error ScreenShot]

**Directory Structure**

```
───pages
│   └───Work
│       │   index.vue
│       │   [Work].vue
```

**Template**

```html
<template>
  <h1>{{ projectTitle }}</h1>
</template>
```

**Script**

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
import {computed} from "vue";
import {useRoute} from "vue-router";

const route = useRoute()

const projectTitle = computed(()=>{
    const title = route.params.work // route param looklike => my-portfolio-project
    return title.replaceAll(/-/g, ' ')
})

</script>
```

Comment: its pretty clear, `title` could theoretically be an array of string. Try to add an check first like  `Array.isArray(title)`

Comment: @bill.gates I `console.log()` this and It's log `false`

Comment: Not console log, use  `if (!Array.isArray(title)) {  }` and typescript will inherit it as an `string` inside the if statement

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs because `replace.all` is a method that was not available earlier. The replaceAll method is defined inside `lib.es2021.string.d.ts`

In your tsconfig.json, add this compiler options:

```
{
    ...,
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...,
        "lib": [
          ...,
          "ES2021.String"
        ]
    }
}
```